# Java: replacing each line with an HTML paragraph

Tags: java

I'm writing a text to HTML converter.
I'm looking for a simple way to wrap each line of text (which ends with carriage return) with

```
<p>.....text.....</p>
```

Can you suggest some String replacement/regular expression that will work in Java ?
Thanks

Comment: No we can't. Please tell us what you tried.

Comment: StringTokenizer with "\n" as separator. Adding text at the beginning and end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String txtFileContent = ....;
String htmlContent = "<p>" + txtFileContent.replaceAll("\\n","</p>\\n<p>") + "</p>";
```

Assuming,

1. line delimitter is "\n".
2. One line is one paragraph.
3. The end of txtFileContent is not "\n"

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

Try using `StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml` and then adding the tags you want at the beginning end.

```
    String escapeHTML = StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml(inputStr);
    String output = "<p>"+escapeHTML+"</p>";
```